# Suspend System Shutdown for a period of time in C#/VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I have created a windows service in C# .net and now I want it to alert me if its going to shutdown. For this I make use of Dispose/Unload events but now I want if the services are stopping due to system shutdown process it will alert me.

So is there any way to get access to system shutdown event and execute the set of commands in it further till the command executes the system remain active booted state and only shut down when the task completes.

Further enhancement to it if I can run it without properly loading of system for example like avast boot time scan.

Comment: Zero accepted answers out of nine questions?

Comment: You can override 
protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            base.OnShutdown();
        }
and onStop().
You could either write to eventlogs or a file (maybe database) and have another program sent mail to admin.

* The other part of "pausing" the shutdown process is tricky (security wise) and is not recommended. OnShutdown event of windows service gets executed on system shutting down. You could write some code to do some "saving" data.

Comment: also please make answers separately so that I can accept one if it works

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is too late, but I just see this question right now :)

You can handle the system event:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded
```

This event will be raised when you shutdown your system or log off from your system. Handle it to do whatever logic you need.

Example:

@OnStart() of your service add the following line of code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);
```

then add the event handler:

```
void SystemEvents_SessionEnded(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventArgs e)
        {
            //put you logic here
        }
```